# seaborn violin plot, how can I set labels?

Tags: seaborn

I'm plotting a list of vectors as a sequence of violin plots.  I'd use a pandas dataframe, but the lists are unequal lengths.

This works:
`python
g = sns.violinplot (data=res, cut=0, inner='box')`

where 'res' is a list of lists (each a vector of floats), where each vector should be turned into a violin.  It is.

but the x axis is just labeled '0,1,2...'.
Adding the parameter 'names=[0,1,2...]' is silently ignored.

Answer (score 8):

You can use the `.set_xticklabels()` method:

```
ax = sns.violinplot(data=res, cut=0, inner='box')
ax.set_xticklabels(['a','b','c'...])
```

Example:

```
import numpy as np, seaborn as sns

res = [i for i in (np.random.randn(3, 25))]
ax = sns.violinplot(data=res, cut=0, inner='box')
ax.set_xticklabels(['a','b','c'])
```

Results in:

[image]

Comment: Call the return value `ax`, not `g`, because `violinplot` returns an `Axes` not a `Grid` object.

Comment: @mwaskom: Thank you updated. Btw, `seaborn` is absolutely amazing.

Comment: @VorsprungdurchTechnik I'm seeing an output of `[Text(0, 0, 'a'),
 Text(0, 0, 'b'),
 Text(0, 0, 'c')]` Proper way to avoid it? `sns.violinplot(data=res).set_xticklabels(['a','b','c'])` does work.

Comment: @5ervant: there's nothing wrong, per se, about the label output and both approaches work fine.

Answer (score 2):

```
ax = sns.violinplot(data=rescaledX,   inner='quartile')
ax.set_xticklabels(bos.columns)
ax.set_title('Distribution of Boston Housing Data Set', fontsize=16);
```

[Violin Plot of Boston Housing Data with Labeled Columns](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cqs4Q.png)